# Link of a PDF not working in Mozilla but works in Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I made a button for a PDF download that is working well in Chrome but it doesn´t open in Mozilla.

This is the code I used:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://gerster.com/docs/posamenten_neuheiten_2014_2.pdf">Jetzt PDF-Katalog herunterladen</a>
```

What could be wrong?

Note: No error is showing up.

Comment: What happens in Mozilla?

Comment: for me its downloading in both browsers.. Are you expecting something else?

Comment: its working fine in mozilla...

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** *Using window.open or "target=" such as blank it doesn´t open in ###  Browser
> What could be wrong?*

**It is up to each user** to download or permit binary.PDF running in a browser viewport after download, this is especially true after download fron any non trusted site.

OOB **many browsers assume they can sandbox the PDF download** and then allow as default action review of the PDF file. Chromeium based browsers like Edge may be more inclined to use that before the user improves their security.

So the 1st task for a user should be to switch off Edge auto viewing of PDFs and switch to a more secure setting.

In that case Edge / Chrome and other browsers will NOT auto run the downloaded PDF but ask the user if they wish to View after Download or simply Download.

> One of the possible values of that attribute is _blank, which tells the browser to open a new window (or tab, if that’s the user’s preference) when that link is clicked.

> This used to be “invalid” in HTML

see [A Bad Reason: The link is to a PDF](https://css-tricks.com/use-target_blank/#aa-a-bad-reason-the-link-is-to-a-pdf)

> If you are going to do it, not only do you need the target attribute for the functionality, you need to rel attribute for security.

So do not open yourserver to security issues blacklist or pop-up blocking see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/

> Don’t use target=_blank (or any other target that opens a new navigation context), especially for links in user-generated content, unless you have a good reason